# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application using a socket as a global variable to share between activities and threads

Tags: android, sockets, object, manifest, global

in my android application I have a socket, but when I rotate the screen, I have to keep the socket connected, to send messages to a server. So I decided to do this:

```
package pfg.nao.naoControler;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.Socket;

import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Application;

public class clientSocket extends Application{

public Socket clientSocket;

@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
    super.onCreate();
}

public void setSocket(Socket socket) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{

    clientSocket = socket;
}

public Socket getSocket() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{

    return clientSocket;
}

}
```

A global socket to use it in my activities and threads. Because I have to be able to open and close the connection in some cases.

For example, I try to access to clientSocket like this:

```
Socket c = new Socket(IP, puerto);
((clientSocket)this.getApplication()).setSocket(c);
```

But I have this error:

```
06-24 22:25:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25267): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 22:25:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25267): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
06-24 22:25:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at pfg.nao.naoControler.NaoControlerActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(NaoControlerActivity.java:160)
06-24 22:25:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2312)
06-24 22:25:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:769)
06-24 22:25:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
06-24 22:25:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
06-24 22:25:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:532)
06-24 22:25:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
06-24 22:25:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9262)
06-24 22:25:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-24 22:25:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-24 22:25:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-24 22:25:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3744)
06-24 22:25:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 22:25:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-24 22:25:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-24 22:25:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-24 22:25:18.217: E/AndroidRuntime(25267):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here it is my android manyfest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="pfg.nao.naoControler"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".NaoControlerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/settings" >
    </activity>
</application>
<application
    android:name=".clientSocket"
    android:label="@string/cliente" >
</application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can read [**this article**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) about how to handle configuration changes (i.e. preventing the activity from being destroyed on an orientation change). Be wary of using it though... there are many ways an activity can be destroyed... not just through an orientation change.

Comment: Just as a general Java comment, using standard naming conventions makes it a lot easier on people trying to read your code.  You have a class named **exactly** the same as a member variable inside it.  That's beyond confusing.  Class names should start with upper case, member variables should start in lower case, and a `Socket` is not the same thing as an `Application`, so try not to name `Application` subclasses things like `clientSocket`, or even `ClientSocket`. Helping you debug your code is easier when it's cleanly written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'd probably do (just based on the info you've given) is make the `Socket` accessible via static method. This way you don't have to worry about whether or not the `Application` is initialized, or if you're calling the right `Application` object.

Something like this (renamed a couple things to avoid confusion...):

```
public class clientSocket extends Application {
    private static Socket localSocket;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public static void setSocket(Socket socket) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        localSocket = socket;
    }

    public static Socket getSocket() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        // Check here if it's null; if it is, then initialize it, or throw some exception, or something.
        return localSocket;
    }
}
```

Then, you can initialize it like this:

```
Socket c = new Socket(IP, puerto);
clientSocket.setSocket(c);
```

And you can call it like this:

```
Socket c = clientSocket.getSocket();
```

Keep in mind: this method will **only** work if you have just **one** `Socket` that you are sharing between classes. If you have multiple, you would have to array them, have multiple classes (with their own `Socket`s), or multiple static `Socket` objects in your class.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer you use as "correct"--it helps people find it in the future!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you implement a [**service**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) and move/centralise all your socket connection code into the service. For all activities that want to use the socket connection, bind your network service in `onCreate` then after the activity is `finish`ed, unbind it in `onDestory()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a fully qualified name of your custom application class in `AndroidManifest.xml` like that:

```
<application android:name="pfg.nao.naoControler.clientSocket" />
```

I believe that is a reason of `ClassCastException` in this line:

```
((clientSocket)this.getApplication()).setSocket(c);
```

Also as [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) reference stays, it's better to use a singleton instead.